# ListView is Widget(View) or Layout(Viewgroup)?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need your help to explore few topics in Android.

My understanding is Widget is View and Layout is ViewGroups in Android.

I described the problems as below-

1. Please go through the below links-

developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html- (add http:// in the beginning)

developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html - (add http:// in the beginning)

In the first link ListView is included as Widget and in the Second link ListView has been shown as Layout.

So, is ListView is Widget(View) or Layout(Viewgroup)?

1. Same is the case for Spinner in Andriod

   developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html- (add http:// in the beginning)
   (Link- says Spinner is Widget(View))

developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html- (add http:// in the beginning)
says Spinner is Layout(ViewGroup)

So, Spinner is View or ViewGroup?

Please update me with your views?

Answer (score 5):

By looking at the class hierarchy, you should be able to find the answer to your question.  The base class is `android.view.View`  which is described as:

> This class represents the basic
>   building block for user interface
>   components. A View occupies a
>   rectangular area on the screen and is
>   responsible for drawing and event
>   handling. View is the base class for
>   widgets, which are used to create
>   interactive UI components (buttons,
>   text fields, etc.). The ViewGroup
>   subclass is the base class for
>   layouts, which are invisible
>   containers that hold other Views (or
>   other ViewGroups) and define their
>   layout properties

This describes the widget concept in Android too.  Any interactive visual component is considered a widget.  You will find these components grouped in the `android.widget` [package](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/package-summary.html).

`ViewGroup` inherits from `View`.  Layouts and more complex widgets like Spinner in turn inherit from `ViewGroup`.

So, `Spinner` is both a `View` and a `ViewGroup`, since it inherits from both.  It is also a widget.  The same is true for `ListView`.